# How to delete nodes

Tags: c++, linked-list, nodes

I need to add a CD with all of its songs to a collection. I'm trying to figure out how to remove a CD from a CD collection. For example, When I append the artist name, the name of the CD, and the title, and length of each song and call the display function it displays all of the information. When I call the `deleteNode` function with the artist, name of CD, and length of CD as parameters, the display function still displays what I appended. The program builds fine but I don't think I'm calling the `deleteNode` function correctly. Also, the linked list has the data type of the class.

The Struct

```
class CD
{
private:
  string artist; // To hold artist nam
  string name;   // To hold name of CD

struct disc
{
    string title;  // To hold title of the song
    double length; // To hold length of the song
    }my_disc;
}
```

Calling the `deleteNode` function from main

```
void remove_cd(LinkedList1<CD> *remove)
{
    cout << "Enter the name of the artist of the CD you wish to remove: ";
    cin.ignore();
    getline(cin, artist);
    cout << "Enter the title: ";
    cin >> title;
    cout << "Enter the length: ";
    cin >> length;
    CD removeNode(artist, title, length);
    remove->deleteNode(removeNode);
}
```

If I use the `artist`, `name`, and `length`) as parameters for `deleteNode` how do I get it to remove all of the songs that have been inserted too? I want to actually delete the CD

The `deleteNode` function in the linkedlist

```
template <class T>
  void LinkedList1<T>::deleteNode( T searchValue)
{
    discList **pp = &head;

    while (*pp && (*pp)->value != searchValue)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (*pp)
    {
        discList *victim = *pp;
        *pp = victim->next;
        delete victim;
    }
}
```

Overloaded operators in CD

```
bool CD::operator == (const CD &e)
{
    if (artist == e.artist)
        return true;
    return false;
}
bool CD::operator != (const CD &e)
{
    if (artist != e.artist)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to use a minimal code as necessary. Please tell me if you need to see anymore code.

Comment: See how is make from liked list data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't think of something much shorter without entering into the ill-advised land of recursion, and even then it would be a stretch.

This will do what you want.

```
template<typename T>
void LinkedList1<T>::deleteNode(const T& searchValue)
{
    discList **pp = &head;

    while (*pp && (*pp)->value != searchValue)
        pp = &(*pp)->next;

    if (*pp)
    {
        discList *victim = *pp;
        *pp = victim->next;
        delete victim;
    }
}
```

And before you ask, yes, it works with an empty list and a null head pointer. This algorithm uses the actual pointers *in* the actual list, not just their values, *the pointers*, to traverse and destroy. It assumes your list is also terminated with NULL..

Finally, your algorithm (and this one) relies on there being an logical-equality operator defined for `CD`, of which I see none. If you've not implemented one yet, you need to do so.

Comment: Thanks. I will try this when I get home. I have overloaded == and != operators in CD. `discList` is the name of the struct in the linked list.

Comment: @Lilspree ok. then that makes sense. I thought it was from something else. this should work for you then.

Comment: Ok I just checked it but when I call my display function it still displays the stuff I appended. Maybe there is something wrong with the way I append it? If I post the append code could you look at it?

Comment: I'll need more code, but this function *provably* removes matching elements. Either the equality operator isn't doing its job (easy to test, looks for a known element and debug this function), or you're passing copies of your container into whatever eventually calls this.

Comment: I updated code with what you suggested. I also added the overloaded operators above

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to use a minimal code as necessary.

I'm so happy that you've added that comment. You can simply use an [`std::list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) like this:

```
class CD {
private:
    std::string artist; // To hold artist nam
    std::string name;   // To hold name of CD
    struct disc {
        std::string title;  // To hold title of the song
        double length; // To hold length of the song
    } my_disc;
};

std::list<CD> list;
```

add a node with:

```
list.emplace_back(/* args for CD constructor */);
```

and delete a node with:

```
list.pop_back();
```

This is as minimal and as error free it can get. Of course if you feel the weight of the double-linked list implementation you can fall back to [`std::forward_list`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/forward_list) any time you want.

Comment: I think he might need to actually devise how to remove an item from a home-made linked list all by himself, in which case `std::list` and the like won't do him any good. Still, yours is a good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the responses unfortunately this `deleteNode` function is the one I was told to use and it may or may not need changing. I appended the nodes using  `CD songsInfo(artist, title, length);'   `append->appendNode(songsInfo);` and a loop appended the songs.

Answer (score 0):

its c++, but can be useful.

```
template<class CAdat>
bool List<CAdat>::Delete(const string &name) {
    Node *tmp = head->next;
    while (tmp != head && tmp->data.getName() != name) {
        tmp = tmp->next;
    }
    if (tmp != head) {
        tmp->prev->next = tmp->next;
        tmp->next->prev = tmp->prev;
        delete tmp;
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: What about the case in which the list is empty? `head` will hold a null pointer, so line `head->next` will make the entire world to come to an end.